# How we can download wso2IS-KM 5.6 version source

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I am using wso2 Api manager 2.5 with wso2is-Km 5.6.0 as key manager. But in github wso2 repository I didn't get any source code as I wanted to change some code in wso2is-Km 5.6.0. How can I download the source code.

Comment: but the source code of api manager don't have Wso2Is-Km 5.6.0 module

Answer (score 1):

Assume that you are a community user and doesn't have a paid subscription. In that case, the publicly available source code will match your binaries.

IS-KM product contains of many modules and their source codes are distributed amongsts multiple git organizations as below.

1. https://github.com/wso2
2. https://github.com/wso2-extensions
3. https://github.com/wso2-attic

You will have to decide the component that you want to checkout and search in these git organizations.

P.S. [This shell script (find-source.sh)](https://github.com/rushmin/dev-tools) might come in handy.